# Why the strcat function move the pointer to the next character?

Tags: c, string, strcat

So, my problem is pretty simple, I don't know why the first segment of code does not work properly.
The program read a string of 12 characters from a pipe and the strcat fuction moves the pointer of buff from the first character to the next every time the fuction is executed and so after a few interactions the read function make the program fail because the buffer is not big enough anymore.
Using the sprintf function and another string solve the issue but i don't understand what cause the problem.
Thanks for the help.

```
int n; 
char buff[15];
close(fd[1]);
    while(n = read(fd[0],buff,12) > 0){      
        strcat(buff,"\n");
        write(1,buff,13); 
        buff[0] = '\0'; 
        }
```

```
int n; 
char buff[15];
char output[15];
close(fd[1]);
while(n = read(fd[0],buff,12) > 0){      
            sprintf(output,"%s\n",buff); 
            write(1,output,13); 
            buff[0] = '\0';       
        }
```

Comment: Lookup the descriptions of `strcat` and `sprintf`!

Comment: `while(n = read(fd[0],buff,12) > 0)` is also wrong. Lookup the precedence of `=` and `>`

Comment: And `write(1,output,13);`: why write 13 bytes if you first asked `n`?

Comment: It is not the first character but that last character that is moved.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `fd[1]` vs 1. They aren't the same

Comment: Compile with `-Wall -Wextra` and read the warnings

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `fd` is not declared here. How did you get the knowledge?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `fd[1]` can be anything. `fd` is just some array the OP defined somewhere. It's possibly filled by [pipe](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe)

Comment: @Kevin, my bad, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper code terminates the buffer, which is assumed to contain a string read:

```
int n;
char buff[15];
close(fd[1]);
while((n = read(fd[0],buff,12)) > 0){
    buff[n] = '\0'; /* add terminating null-character */
    strcat(buff,"\n");
    write(1,buff,n+1);
}
```

and

```
int n;
char buff[15];
char output[15];
close(fd[1]);
while((n = read(fd[0],buff,12)) > 0){
    buff[n] = '\0'; /* add terminating null-character */
    sprintf(output,"%s\n",buff);
    write(1,output,n+1);
}
```

- Note the extra `(` and `)` in the assignment to `n`
- Note the use of `n`, the *actual* number of characters read
- And note, as Mike said, the termination of the string.

Answer (score -1):

`strcat` and `%s` specifier of `sprintf` expects *strings*, which means "*null-terminted* sequence of characters" in C.

If the contents from the pipe is not guaranteed to null-terminated, you have to add terminating null-character.

```
int n;
char buff[15];
close(fd[1]);
while(n = read(fd[0],buff,12) > 0){
    buff[12] = '\0'; /* add terminating null-character */
    strcat(buff,"\n");
    write(1,buff,13);
    buff[0] = '\0';
}
```

```
int n;
char buff[15];
char output[15];
close(fd[1]);
while(n = read(fd[0],buff,12) > 0){
    buff[12] = '\0'; /* add terminating null-character */
    sprintf(output,"%s\n",buff);
    write(1,output,13);
    buff[0] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: `buf[n]='\0';` you mean?

Comment: No need for `buff[0] = '\0'` I think (when using `n`)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `buff[0] = '\0'` is not needed even without `n` (if `buff` is not used after the loop) because `buff[0]` will be overwritten by successful `read` anyway.